# 'gradle clean build assemble' giving IOException: The pipe is being closed

Tags: gradle, build, assemble

I cleared my .gradle folder (local gradle repository). The command 'gradle clean build assemble' used to work earlier but now giving the exception as below :

```
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 120.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

However the command 'gradle clean build assemble -x test' still works and yields a successful build. What shall be done to get the 'gradle clean build assemble' command working again ?